# Change tag in tinyMCEPopup editor dom element

Tags: tinymce

In the `tinyMCEPopup.editor.dom`, it has a `div` element like below,

```
<div id="item1" class="classname">
  <!-- item content goes here -->
</div>
```

I need to change the `div` element to `ul` programmatically by using `tinyMCEPopup` without changing the content or class name.

I have selected the element like below,

```
tinyMCEPopup.editor.dom.select('#item1');
```

However, I have no idea how to change the `div` to `ul`.

 Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to create a new `ul` element in the dom. And replacing the existing `div` with that.

```
var prevElement = tinyMCEPopup.editor.dom.select('#item1')[0];
var newUL = tinyMCEPopup.editor.dom.create('ul', { id: 'item1', 'class': 'classname' }, '');
newUL.innerHTML = prevElement.innerHTML();
tinyMCEPopup.editor.dom.select('#item1')[0].parentNode.replaceChild(newUL, prevElement);
```